# Turn off BitLocker Drive Encryption (BDE) running only Ubuntu

Tags: bios

I'm trying to updating BIOS on my Notebook HP Elitebook 840 G9.

I'm running **only** Ubuntu (22.04) on this Notebook.

While updating BIOS a message appears (ca.) "Turn off BitLocker Drive Encryption BDE in order to process with BIOS update".

I have a NVME Drive:

```
smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1
<...>
Model Number:                       SAMSUNG MZVL4512HBLU-00BH1
<...>
Firmware Version:                   HPS3NHAV
<...>
```

How can I disable/turn off this specific Windows feature **from** Ubuntu in order to proceed with BIOS update?

Current BIOS is: `UEFI: HP v: U76 Ver. 01.05.00 date: 01/06/2023`
It is already a version `01.07.00` available.

Note: this Notebook is labeled with "HP Wolf Security" and "EVO" labels.

Comment: Bitlocker only affects the Windows partition and drive.  It doesn't affect the firmware on the system for BIOS.  That's a HP thing, not a Linux or Bitlocker thing

Comment: I have saccessful installed Ubuntu on this drive and run it. But BIOS/UEFI update fails. I have tried with different methods of an UEFI updates. Only network update seems to work, but I fail at this error message.

Comment: @klpu39 how are you updating the bios/uefi? Is there a utility from HP to run from Ubuntu/Linux? Thanks.

Comment: I'm tried updating from NVME/Flash drive. The BIOS/UEFI sees new version, but in the next step update fails, because he "does not find the firmware on this flash drive" :\

Comment: @klpu39 so if we go by your own words: "in the next step update fails, because he "does not find the firmware on this flash drive"", the issue does not seems to be related to BitLocker or Ubuntu. It's hard to tell without knowing what exact software/utility available from HP to update the bios/uefi but it sounds like problem could be with how are you preparing flash drive to boot the PC. Thanks.

Comment: @Jags i just described that the method of updating from usb flash fails. Network update fails with described error "bitlocker.. etc".

Comment: I was able update BIOS/UEFI firmware from commandline with `fwupd-tool`. Now I have `UEFI: HP v: U76 Ver. 01.08.01 date: 07/18/2023`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able update BIOS/UEFI firmware from commandline with `fwupd`-tool. Now I have `UEFI: HP v: U76 Ver. 01.08.01 date: 07/18/2023`.